# Return dictionary key containing two specific values

Tags: python, dictionary, key, element

I come today with a rather simple problem. I have a dictionary with keys containing a list of elements. I know how to return the key if it contains one specific value but how can I do it if I am looking for two specific values together?

Let's suppose I have a dict called my_dict, with keys (0 to 10) and list of words for each key.

Ex:

```
my_dict = {
    0 : ['bear', 'tiger', 'lion'], 
    1: ['cheetah', 'tiger', 'snake'], 
    2: ['bear', 'tiger', 'elephant'], 
    # and so on...
}
```

I want to return the keys for which I have the words bear and tiger together :)

Thank you in advance

Comment: So, when you want the keys with bear and tiger together, I suppose the output should be `[0, 2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
my_dict = {0 : ['bear', 'tiger', 'lion'], 1: ['cheetah', 'tiger', 'snake'], 2: ['bear', 'tiger', 'elephant']}
keys = []
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    if 'bear' in v and 'tiger' in v:
        keys.append(k)
print(keys)  # [0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate and do a simple check

```
>>> my_dict = {0 : ['bear', 'tiger', 'lion'], 1: ['cheetah', 'tiger', 'snake'], 2: ['bear', 'tiger', 'elephant']}
>>>
>>> [x for x,y in my_dict.items() if 'bear' in y and 'tiger' in y]
[0, 2]
```

Comment: why can't you do `if 'bear' and 'tiger' in y` ?

Comment: @lalithkumar That would evaluate to `True and 'tiger' in y` rendering it useless

Comment: Or use the `all` operator, i.e. `[k for k,v in my_dict.items() if all(s in v for s in ("tiger","bear"))]`

Answer (score 0):

iterate the dictionary using items function, check the existence of value 1 then value 2 in dictionary list value if found return the key. Below is example code which can be customised based on need:

```
my_dict = {101 : ['bear', 'tiger', 'lion'], 100: ['cheetah', 'tiger', 'snake'], 102: ['bear', 'tiger', 'elephant']}
def get_dict_key(val1,val2):
    for k,v in my_dict.items():
        if val1 in v:
            if val2 in v:
                return k

get_dict_key('cheetah','tiger')
```